# Pythonic counting and scraping to skip first table if two tables exist

Tags: python, count, beautifulsoup, finance, edgar

I'm trying to get .xml data from SEC filings. It's in the [second table.](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1070789/000149315217011092/0001493152-17-011092-index.htm)
But, if I get to a page that doesn't have the .xml, I want the html vers, [first & only table.](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1592603/000139160917000254/0001391609-17-000254-index.htm)
Could someone please help me understand how to iterate or skip a the first table if there are two, and to get the first a['href'] in the first table if only one is present?

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tableCount = 0
linklist = [https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1070789/000149315217011092/0001493152-17-011092-index.htm, https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1592603/000139160917000254/0001391609-17-000254-index.htm]
for l in linklist:
html = urlopen(l)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('latin-1', 'ignore'),"lxml")    
table = soup.findAll(class_='tableFile') # works for getting all .htm links
for item in table:
    tableCount +=1
url = table[0].a["href"]
if table.count >= 1:
    url = table[1].a["href"]
else:
    url = table.a["href"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need the info from last table in both cases, so you can use index -1 of list to get the last table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1070789/000149315217011092/0001493152-17-011092-index.htm',
        'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1592603/000139160917000254/0001391609-17-000254-index.htm']
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    tables = soup.findAll('table', class_='tableFile')

    # assume xml table always comes after html one
    table = tables[-1]
    for a in table.findAll('a'):
        print(a['href'])  # you may filter out txt or xsd here
```